# How can I retrieve a Django model element by name, regardless of text case?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can i get element by name despite of text register.

for example in my models i have element with user_name equal to "hello world" and i want get this element.

So i write:

```
User.objects.get(user_name=name)
```

It's working if name equal to "hello world", but if name equal to "Hello World" or "hElLO wOrLD" then it's not working.

I can use name.lower() but if user_name from models equal to "HELLO WORLD" then it's not working again.

Answer (score 2):

You work with the [**`__iexact`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
User.objects.get(user_name__iexact=name)
```

> I can use `name.lower()` but if `user_name` from models equal to `"HELLO WORLD"` then it's not working again.

Even if that would work, it is a common misconception that calling `.lower()` on both operands performs case in-sensitive matching. For a lot of characters, their are no lowercase/uppercase variants, and in some languages the rules when two items are equivalent are "complicated". One uses [**`str.casefold(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) to convert it to a variant to perform case-insensitive matches.